# If $a,b,c$ are in $A.P.$ then prove that $b^2>ac$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

If $a,b,c$ are in $A.P.$ then prove that $b^2>ac$

My Attempt:

$a,b,c$ are in AP
$$b=\dfrac {a+c}{2}$$

Also,
$$A.M>G.M$$
$$\dfrac {a+b}{2}>\sqrt {ab}$$

Comment: Note that $a$,$b$,$c$ can be negative.  I would not use AM/GM, just take $b=(a+c)/2$ as you have done and write out equivalences for the inequality $b^2>ac$.  [This of course assumes the case $a=b=c$ is not allowed, else it would be $\geq$ not $>$.]

Comment: Write $a$ and $c$ in terms of $b$ and the common difference $d = b-a$.

Comment: three consecutive terms or any three terms?  Note $b = (c -d) = (a+d)$ so $b^2 = (c-d)(a+d) = ac +(c-a)d - d^2 = ac + 2d*d -d^2 = ac + d^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$b = (a+c)/2$,
we have

$\begin{array}\\
b^2-ac
&=(a+c)^2/4-ac\\
&=(a^2+2ac+c^2)/4-ac\\
&=(a^2-2ac+c^2)/4\\
&=(a-c)^2/4\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{array}
$

with equality
if and only if
$a = c$.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward: b=a+x, c=a+2x, $ac=a(a+2x)=a^2+2ax\lt b^2=(a+x)^2=a^2+2ax+x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, presumabaly $b = a + d=c-d;$ and $c = a + 2d$.

So $b^2 = (c-d)(a+d) = ac +(c-a)d - d^2 = ac + 2d*d -d^2 = ac + d^2$.